# Bezier animation to reveal and conceal a checkmark with Swift

Tags: ios, swift

In my app I have a checkmark inside a UIView which I reveal or conceal depending on the button the user clicks on to create the effect that the checkmark is being drawn or erased. I am using Bezier path with a mask to animate the checkmark being revealed or concealed with the code shown below. However, in the code to conceal it, the checkmark is being concealed from right to left and I would like to do it from left to right. What am I missing?

***Code to reveal the checkmark***

```
func checkmarkAnimationToReveal(view: UIView) {

        let path                = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRectMake(0, 0, view.bounds.width / 10, view.bounds.height))
        let mask                = CAShapeLayer()
        mask.anchorPoint        = CGPointMake(0.5, 1.0)
        mask.path               = path.CGPath

        view.layer.mask = mask

        let anim                = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "path")

        anim.fromValue          = path.CGPath
        anim.toValue            = UIBezierPath(rect:view.bounds).CGPath
        anim.duration           = 1.0
        anim.fillMode           = kCAFillModeForwards
        anim.removedOnCompletion = false
        view.layer.mask!.addAnimation(anim, forKey: "anim")

    }
```

***Code to conceal the checkmark***

```
func checkmarkAnimationToConceal(view: UIView) {

    CATransaction.begin()
    CATransaction.setCompletionBlock({
        print("completion reached")
        self.checkmarkLabel.hidden = true
    })

    let path                = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRectMake(0, 0, view.bounds.width / 10, view.bounds.height))
    let mask                = CAShapeLayer()
    mask.anchorPoint        = CGPointMake(0.5, 1.0)
    mask.path               = path.CGPath

    view.layer.mask = mask

    let anim                = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "path")

    anim.fromValue          = UIBezierPath(rect:view.bounds).CGPath
    anim.toValue            = path.CGPath
    anim.duration           = 1.0
    anim.fillMode           = kCAFillModeRemoved
    anim.removedOnCompletion = false
    view.layer.mask!.addAnimation(anim, forKey: "anim")

}
```

Comment: Why it has the same anumation's key? `view.layer.mask!.addAnimation(anim, forKey: "anim")`

Comment: doesn't matter since I have not need to use the key in my case, I could make it nil